# Drupal 6 site + Facebook new Graph API intros?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to integrate one of my Drupal site with Facebook API. One of my questions is:

- after a user login my Drupal site
- how can my site tell whether the user:

  1. has `Like`d one of my Drupal pages or not
  2. and redirect the user to a different page based on `Like`d/Not yet `Like`d

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "[Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect)" module for easing connection to facebook. After this you can use graph api:

```
$fb = facebook_client();
$response = $fb->api('/me/likes');
print_r($response);
```